# Limits in Indeterminate form.

Tags: real-analysis

Why is the   $\lim_{x  \rightarrow \ 0}$$x^x$ indeterminate and not $1$ ?.

I first approached this as the zero polynomial, but still couldn't wrap my head around why this would still be an indeterminate form.

Comment: That is because $0^0$ is *not* defined. Note that, since $x$ is not a constant, $x^x$ can 't be considered a polynomial.

Comment: Also, the limit from the left does not exist.

Comment: Note that the limit from the right is $1$, though.

Comment: Ah alright. Thanks, my error was assuming that $x^x$ can be "considered" to behave like a polynomial around 0, especially when it is of the form/around $0^0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $e^{lnx}=x$ to rewrite the problem as $$\lim_{x\to 0} e^{lnx^x}=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{xlnx}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}xlnx}=e^0=1$$

Comment: This is a bit incomplete.  What if the limit is approached from the left-hand side?

Answer (score -1):

The limit as $x$ goes to $0$ from *above* is $1$ - but the notation $\lim_{x \to 0}x^x$ means "the limit from *both sides*". For negative values of $x$, $x^x$ is often undefined - for example, $(-\frac{1}{2})^{-1/2}$ or $(-\frac{1}{4})^{-1/4}$. Since we run into this issue at $-2^{-n}$ for every $n$ - not to mention every irrational negative value of $x$ - the limit from the left can't be said to exist, let alone be equal to $1$.

Comment: I think that $\lim_{x\to0}x^x$ doesn't means "the limit from both sides". By definition of limit:


Let $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function, $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ an accumulation point for D, $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$ then


$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\ell\iff\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 \mbox{ s. t if } x\in D\wedge 0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$.


If $D=(0,+\infty)$ and $x_0=0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ means $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)$.

Comment: @Ixion That's correct, but by convention, when the domain of a function is not given it is assumed to be the whole space. Thus if we had said "let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x^x$" then certainly $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 1$. But without qualification, $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x$ considers all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MarkViola Hm? If $n$ is odd, $(-1/n)^{-1/n}$ is strictly negative. The limit cannot possibly be $1$ for complex numbers. You're assuming a continuous extension of $\ln{x}$ to complex numbers, which does not exist.

Comment: @MarkViola But such replacements can't be done inside a limit. In this case, notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(-\frac{1}{2n+1})^{-1/(2n + 1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}-(2n + 1)^{1/(2n + 1)} = -1$, so there are values of $x$ arbitrarily near zero for which $x^x = -1$. The limit can't be $1$.

Comment: @MarkViola Nope, never mind! Studying your argument more closely, I realize I was wrong about the error. $e^{ix\textrm{arg}(x)}$ doesn't go to $1$ - it goes to a point on the unit circle in the direction of $x$.